# Is this Red-Black tree insertion pseudocode from Introduction to Algorithms (CLRS) correct?

Tags: algorithms, trees, binary-tree

For the Red-black tree insertion fixup the book distinguishes between 6 cases, 3 of which are symmetric.
The cases are (z is the node being inserted):

- Case 1: z's uncle is red
- Case 2: z's uncle is black and z is a right child
- Case 3: z's uncle is black and z is a left child

Case 2 is a subset of case 3, as we can transform Case 2 into 3 with a left rotation.

However in the book's pseudocode which you can see [here](https://books.google.se/books?id=aefUBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=introduction%20to%20algorithms&pg=PA316#v=onepage&q&f=false) or [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-10-red-black-trees-rotations-insertions-deletions/lec10.pdf#page=24) they write as follows:

```
if uncle.color == red:
  # Handle case
else if z == z.p.right:
  # Handle case 2
  # Handle case 3
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
if uncle.color == red:
  # Handle case
else:
  if z == z.p.right:
    # Handle case 2
  # Handle case 3
```

Am I missing something? Does the book use `else if` in a different way than say Python does? The C++ implementation provided [here](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/software/AlgAnim/red_black.html) uses the second version as I expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The indentation in the code is important:

```
if uncle.color == red:
     # Handle case
else if z == z.p.right:
          # Handle case 2
     # Handle case 3
```

The syntax is a bit quirky, because they squished the `if` to appear on the same line as the `else`, but case 2 is indented further inward compared to the remaining case 3, indicating that they do not belong to the same group.

This is what I think the author intended:

```
if (uncle.color == red) 
{
   # Handle case
} 
else 
{ 
    if (z == z.p.right) 
    {
         # Handle case 2 
    }
    # Handle case 3 
}
```

Comment: Yeah after looking at it some more it makes sense. Still it's not immediately obvious, bad choice of optimizing for LOC vs. readability.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: the code was deliberately written such a contorted way to show where the blocks begin and end.